# Angular5 Perfect Scrollbar psYReachEnd fires event multiple times

Tags: angular, angular5, perfect-scrollbar

I am utilizing ngx-perfect-scrollbar 5.5.12 for my Angular5 app.

When the scrollbar reach the bottom of the screen, I am going to load more data like infinite scrolling.

**app.component.html**

```
<perfect-scrollbar
    [config]="config"
    (psYReachEnd)="onReachEnd()">
```

But the problem is that it fires the method **multiple times**.

**app.component.ts**

```
  onReachEnd() {
    console.log('log several times here');
  }
```

I am not sure if this is fixed in later versions but I am now utilizing v.5.5.12.

Is there a way to fix this?
Or any alternative ways?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in my project. Version: "7.1.0".

So my solution for that is to create some boolean variable for loading more items.
When you are loading some data from the API set it to true - after that to false.

Example of using that in your function.

```
onReachEnd(): void {
  if (this.isLoadingData) {
    return;
  }

  // Call the API/function for more items here
}
```

Since I don't know if you have some service for handling requests etc. I will show you some example by using BehaviorSubject.

Let say that you service is named `dataService`.
We can create here `BehaviorSubject` - isLoadingData.

`private isLoadingDataBehaviorSubject BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);`

and since it's service we can create here `public` observable:
`isLoadingData` = this.isLoadingDataBehaviorSubject.asObservable();`

Now when we got that all, we can create function to call API inside this service:

```
loadData(): Observable<any> {
  this.isLoadingDataBehaviorSubject.next(true);
  return this.http.get(url).pipe(
    tap((response) => {
        this.isLoadingDataBehaviorSubject.next(false);
        return response;
    }),
    catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        this.isLoadingDataBehaviorSubject.next(false);
        return of({});
    })
  );
}
```

And you have also to subscribe to this isLoadingData inside your component and set it's value.
Easiest way just for example:

```
ngOnInit(): {
    this.dataService.isLoadingData.subscribe(x => {
        this.isLoadingData = x;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better solution is to verify the "scrollTop" attribute of the scrolling event is non-zero (0 means you are scrolled to the top)

.ts:

```
onScrollToBottom(event) {

    // fix for psYReachEnd event triggering on page load
    if(event.target.scrollTop == 0) {
        return;
    }

    ... <your code here for what to do after scrolling to the bottom>
}
```

HTML:

```
 <perfect-scrollbar (psYReachEnd)="onScrollToBottom($event)">
```